# javascript conditionally disable checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have some input elements and would like to include a checkbox that is disabled if the input elements are not complete. However, I cannot use an onClick attribute. A fiddle is below. As you can see, my goal is that the result checkbox should be disabled if input1 and input2 are left blank. Any advice?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0jozk5uL/

**HTML**

```
Input 1:<select name="input1" id="input1" initialvalue="">
<option class="no-op" value="">-- Please select --</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select><br>
Input 2:<select name="input2" id="input2" initialvalue="">
<option class="no-op" value="">-- Please select --</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select><br>
Result:<input type="checkbox" name="result" id="result">
```

**Javascript**

```
var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');
var result = document.getElementById('result');

function(){
    if(input1 == "" && input2 == ""){
        result.disabled = true;
    } else {
        result.disabled = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check `input1.value == ""`, not simply `input1 == ""`

You also need to fire your method originally, and also run it every time your select lists change value.

Give the function a name

```
function setCheckState(evt) {
    if (input1.value == "" || input2.value == "") {
        result.disabled = true;
    } else {
        result.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Add event listeners

```
input1.addEventListener('change', setCheckState);
input2.addEventListener('change', setCheckState);
```

Fire the method to get the initial checkbox state set

```
setCheckState();
```

See my [update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0jozk5uL/3/)

[Finally](http://jsfiddle.net/0jozk5uL/4/), you can reduce your `if()` statement to a simple assignment...

```
function setCheckState(evt) {
    result.disabled = input1.value == "" || input2.value == "";
}
```

---

[edit] ... thanks dave, based on the question statement *"disabled if the input elements are not complete."* I believe you are correct about using `||` instead of `&&`  ...  updating this answer and making one more [fiddle change](http://jsfiddle.net/0jozk5uL/8/).

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure that is a helpful start, but doesn't solve the problem. I appreciate the quick input.

Comment: It's a little unclear from the post but I think that should be an OR not an AND in the fiddle. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/0jozk5uL/5/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
function update(dropdown, check) {
  if(dropdown.options[dropdown.getSelectedIndex].text != "--Please select--") {
     check.disabled = false; // if value is not equal to --Please select--...
  } else {
     check disabled = true;
  }
}

var check // = checkbox elem

var in1 // = dropdown 1 elem
var in2 // = dropdown 2 elem

in1.onchange = function() {
  update(in1, check); // update checkbox 
}

in2.onchange = function() {
  update(in2, check); // update checkbox
}
```

Hope this helps, sorry for any typing errors, I'm on a phone.

Comment: I respectfully disagree ... I think using the `.value` is more appropriate than using the `.text`, and blindly assigning `.onchange = function...` replaces any existing listeners, while `.addEventListener()` allows building up a series of listeners.

Comment: @StephenP I agree with the event listeners, but I was just writing a quick answer. I don't think there is much of a disadvantage to using .text though, but I am probably less experienced than you.